# For mobile first approach,how to display all table column in desktop size after hiding some column in mobile size

Tags: html, css

There are 3 columns in total, for the desktop version, all column will be shown.
For the mobile version, only the first 2 columns will be shown.
Now, for both the desktop and mobile version, 2 columns are shown. The 3rd column is missing for the desktop version. Any thoughs, thankyou

```css
/* Responsive design for the mobile devices  */


#hide,#hide2 {

    display:none;
 
        position:relative;
        
        margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Responsive design for the desktop devices  */
@media (min-width: 769px) {
 

 
}
```

```html
<table border="2">
<tr>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th id="hide">C</th>
</tr>

<td>Anna</td>
<td>BVen</td>
<td id="hide2">Crys</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Look at my awnser. I made it that it will hide the third colom when the width is max 480px;

Comment: You are hiding something when the screen is larger then 768px;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer changes according to your comment .

```css
/* Responsive design for the mobile devices  */
 #hide,#hide2 {

 display:none;
 
        position:relative;
        
        margin: 0 auto;
}

   

/* Responsive design for the desktop devices  */
@media (min-width: 769px) {
 
        #hide,#hide2 {

 display:block;
 
        position:relative;
        
        margin: 0 auto;
}
 
}
```

```html
<table border="2">
<tr>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th id="hide">C</th>
</tr>

<td>Anna</td>
<td>BVen</td>
<td id="hide2">Crys</td>
</table>
```

Comment: This would hide it on desktop and show on mobile. Opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: opps.. answer edited.Please check again. @kartik Sharma

Comment: this was similar to my original code, as i am now trying to modify my code to become mobile first, so my page could render faster for mobile user. So instead of using media (max-width: 768px) , im trying to use media (min-width: 768px) ,any idea?

Comment: @epiphany ...answer edited as per your requirements.

Comment: i've tried , but the 3 rd column cant show on desktop

Comment: i use display:table-cell and now it work,thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your css is being applied always. Media query is pretty much useless as of now.

```
#hide,#hide2 {
        display:none;
        position:relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Responsive design for the desktop devices  */
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    #hide, #hide2 {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.

```css
/* Responsive design for the desktop  */

/* load normal desktop css */


/* Responsive design for the mobile devices  */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
 
#hide, #hide2 {

    display:none;
        position:relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
 
}
```

```html
<table border="2">
<tr>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th id="hide">C</th>
</tr>

<td>Anna</td>
<td>BVen</td>
<td id="hide2">Crys</td>
</table>
```

Comment: this was similar to my original code, as i am now trying to modify my code to become mobile first, so my page could render faster for mobile user. So instead of using media (max-width: 768px)  , im trying to use media (min-width: 768px) {

Comment: so it will hide it on any screen larger than 768px wihch is not what you want. 
It wont be faster or slower the content is there it is just hidden or change it to max-width so it will hide whenever the screen is smaller than 768px;